# Validation Error with Mini CSS Extract Pluginon NPM run start

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, npm-start, mini-css-extract-plugin

I updated the package extract-text-webpack-plugin to mini-css-extract-plugin in package.json.

when I do
npm run start
I got the below validation error

\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158
throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
^

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Mini CSS Extract Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.

- options should be an object:
  object { filename?, chunkFilename?, experimentalUseImportModule?, ignoreOrder?, insert?, attributes?, linkType?, runtime? }
  at validate ( \node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158:11)
  at new MiniCssExtractPlugin ( \node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:490:5)
  at Object. ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\webpack\webpack.plugins.js:6:18)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
  at Module._compile ( \node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:117:24)
  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
  at Object.newLoader [as .js] ( \node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:121:7)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
  at Object. ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\webpack\base.js:3:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
  at Module._compile ( \node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:117:24)
  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
  at Object.newLoader [as .js] ( \node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:121:7)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
  at module.exports ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\webpack\webpack.config.js:29:20)
  at getWebpackCompiler ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\middleware\webpack.js:17:59)
  at Object.dev ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\middleware\webpack.js:26:42)
  at webpackHotMiddleware ( \node_modules\pivotal-ui\middleware\webpack.js:52:22)
  at module.exports ( \server/app.js:37:16)
  at Object. ( \server\bootstrap.js:5:27)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {

Do we need to update anything after installing the mini-css-extract-plugin package? Help to resolve the issue